# How to change directory in java

Tags: java

I want to unzip tgz files using 7zip utility in Windows OS. My 7zip.exe file is placed in D: drive. My unzip command is `7z e abc.tgz`. This command is working through terminal but not through my java code.

Previously I tried

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("cmd.exe d: ", null, new File("D:\\")); 
Process p=r.exec("7z e abc.tgz"null,new File("D:\\"));
InputStream is=p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line=new String();
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) System.out.println (line);
```

I even tried this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c","start","cmd");
pb = pb.directory(new File("D:"));
pb.command("7z", "e", "abc.tgz");
pb.start();
```

Is there any different method for changing the directory through java?

Comment: the error i am getting is Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "7z e 1.tgz" (in directory "D:\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet to change the working directory:

```
 String[] command = unzip_your_file;
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
 builder.directory(new File("directory_location"));
```